# How to take full application screenshot in android virtual device?

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-studio-2.0

Hey guys i have an application that using scrollview, and i want to take a full screenshot on my avd for my application, but i only getting like half of it because you need to scroll down to view more layout, so how can i take a full screenshot of my application? here's the example:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to view the page in a normal browser, let's say InternetExplorer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution, to take full app screenshot select your xml layout you want to screenshot in res/layout, and go to text tab, and click the camera button on right side, see the image below for example :
[image: solution]

Comment: This does not answer the question for 99% of the applications on the PlayStore. This literally only works for apps that rely on static content purely generated via XML. Your answer does not accomodate for applications which rely on server-side content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in the Android Emulator, you will have to take multiple Screenshots and stitch them together using an graphics editing software like Photoshop or The Gimp.

Another option is using an App like [Panoramic Screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.papdt.pano)